# What will be the placeholder for python3 sqlite table's auto incremented id while inserting data after table creation?

Tags: python, python-3.x, database, sqlite, primary-key

I have created a python3 sqlite table if it doesn't exist with createTable() method. Say after that I want to insert data with the following method (insertVaribleIntoTable()).

Now for this method I don't know the id of the new row after which I will insert the data as it is auto incrementing.

So I didn't pass the id to insertVaribleIntoTable() method. What should I do for the id variable? Can anybody kindly tell me what should I pass as id placeholder to insertVaribleIntoTable() method because it will be incremented automatically as I am inserting data? Can anybody tell me what to do? You can see there is one less "?" after "VALUES" keyword in insertVaribleIntoTable() method. Thank you.

```python
    def createTable(id, name, company, address, postal, country, home, business, mobile, fax, notes):
            
        try:
            sqliteConnection = sqlite3.connect('SQLite_Python.db');
            cursor = sqliteConnection.cursor();
            print("Connected to SQLite");
    
            sqlite_insert_with_param = """CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 'SqliteDb_Addresser' (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name, company, address, postal, country, home, business, mobile, fax, notes) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);""";
    
            data_tuple = (id, name, company, address, postal, country, home, business, mobile, fax, notes);
            cursor.execute(sqlite_insert_with_param, data_tuple);
            sqliteConnection.commit();
            print("Python Variables inserted successfully into SqliteDb_developers table");
    
            cursor.close();
    
        except sqlite3.Error as error:
            print("Failed to insert Python variable into sqlite table", error);
        finally:
            if (sqliteConnection):
                sqliteConnection.close();
                print("The SQLite connection is closed");  
    
    def insertVaribleIntoTable(name, company, address, postal, country, home, business, mobile, fax, notes):
            
        try:
            sqliteConnection = sqlite3.connect('SQLite_Python.db');
            cursor = sqliteConnection.cursor();
            print("Connected to SQLite");
    
            sqlite_insert_with_param = """INSERT INTO 'SqliteDb_Addresser'
                            (name, company, address, postal, country, home, business, mobile, fax, notes) 
                            VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);""";
    
            data_tuple = (name, company, address, postal, country, home, business, mobile, fax, notes);
            cursor.execute(sqlite_insert_with_param, data_tuple);
            sqliteConnection.commit();
            print("Python Variables inserted successfully into SqliteDb_developers table");
    
            cursor.close();
    
        except sqlite3.Error as error:
            print("Failed to insert Python variable into sqlite table", error);
        finally:
            if (sqliteConnection):
                sqliteConnection.close();
                print("The SQLite connection is closed");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the column is auto-increment, then you don't insert that column. It will be created by the database.

If you want to see the last ID inserted, you can use last_insert_rowid()

```
CREATE TABLE Person (
     ID integer primary key AUTOINCREMENT, 
     Name varchar(20), 
     Age Integer 
)

INSERT INTO Person (Name, Age) VALUES ('Tim', 12);  -- Don't include ID

SELECT last_insert_rowid()    -- 1
```

The same idea applies when inserting through code.